# How can I pass an HTML value to a PHP variable

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have a simple web app made with CodeIgniter 3 and I have created a simple dropdown menu where the user can select from a variety of options from the database.
Here is the code:

```
<?php   
        $sql4 = "SELECT DISTINCT (color), id FROM porta_color ORDER BY color ASC "; 
                 $result4 = $conn->query($sql4);
?>

<select id="color" class="form-control selectpicker" data-size="10" data-live-search="true" data-style="btn-white" name="k_color" required  >

<?php 
     if ($result4->num_rows > 0) 
     {
       while($row4 = $result4->fetch_assoc()) 
       {
         if($row4['id']>0)
         {?>
         <option value="<?=$row4['id'];?>"><?=$row4['color'];?></option>
         <?php }}}?>
 </select>
```

Now what I want to do is based on the selection from the user to pass the value to a PHP variable.

Any idea how I might do that?

Comment: If I don't misunderstand, this is about using the form tag? <form action="url_to_pass_vars.php"> <select name='nametag'><option val='1'>option 1 </option></select> </form> and inside the file url_to_pass_vars.php you can retrieve the vars by using $_POST['nametag']. Or you are trying to make an asynchronous call?

Comment: Submit it with a form. Use the global super array $_GET or $_POST (depending on your form method attribute. Make sure you consider SQL injection if this is going to affect a database. If you render anything that's ever been submitted through a form then make sure you escape it in your view.

Comment: selectpicker has events which trigger on change, i.e `sp-change`. plop some ajax code in the event callback, then pick it up in php

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your **select** into [form tags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms)
and add [submit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/submit) or [button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) element

```html
<form>
  <select id="color" class="form-control selectpicker" data-size="10" data-live-search="true" data-style="btn-white" name="k_color" required  >
    <option value="color1">Color 1</option>
    <option value="color2">Color 2</option>
    <option value="color3">Color 3</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" values="Choose color">
  <button>Another way for submit form</button>
</form>
```

But true way is using [framework abilities](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/tutorial/create_news_items.html#create-a-form)